# Background Colour IE7 for table row not working

Tags: css, internet-explorer-7

Pretty weird, fine in all other browser but in IE7 the background colour is not showing the css for the table is as follows.

```
#warrentyFormTable tr.error            { background: #ffe2e2; }
```

Comment: I've found this link related to your question: <http://www.sitepoint.com/forums/showthread.php?683598-Table-Cell-Background-Color-Issue-with-IE7-and-IE6> Do you use a CSS reset and maybe resetted the background-property of **td**-elements to transparent?

Comment: Aye looks like it, good catch

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you use some kind of CSS Reset and the background-property is set to transparent for the td-element, this causes IE6/7 to trouble.

Try only resetting these things you really need and remove **td** from that list.

Further information on this site:
http://www.sitepoint.com/forums/showthread.php?683598-Table-Cell-Background-Color-Issue-with-IE7-and-IE6%3E

Answer (score 0):

It just wont manage TR styling

Try this :

```
#warrentyFormTable tr.error td {background: #ffe2e2}
```

carry on